# Selenium test with junit stop after fixed time

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit, timer, automated-tests

I have selenium test running with junit 4 under Eclipse Luna.
My script stoped (seems to be disconnected) aftera fixed laps of time with success.
I think that there is a tips or configuration required to set more time.
But I cant' find the solution.

[the image of the time passed and success status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecURo.png)

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Can you share your test logic?

Comment: It's a complicated script, ant take long time :/